# How can I submit a folder with subfolders with a form input?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been searching quite a lot, and I currently have an answer for folders without subfolders:

Here's my main.php page with the submit form

```
<form action="uploadproject.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="archive[]" webkitdirectory multiple="">

    <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Here's my uploadproject.php, where I get the submitted folder and move it to my filesystem

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['archive']['name']); $i++) { 
    if ($_FILES['archive']['error'][$i]==0) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archive']['tmp_name'][$i], 'uploads/'.
            $_FILES['archive']['name'][$i]);
    }
}
```

This way I'm basically uploading all the folder contents into my 'uploads' folder.

How can I upload subfolders to 'uploads' as well?

Comment: Take a look here : http://sapphion.com/2012/06/12/keep-directory-structure-when-uploading/

Comment: `webkitdirectory` not working in all browser, it's best you compress folder with .zip and upload as files, and use `php zip` to uncompress. This will keep the path folders.